# Recommend best Free online project managment tool

Tags: project

Can any one recommend me free project managment tool with svn / git integration?

Comment: You might want to check on the PM site.  http://pm.stackexchange.com/search?q=free+project+tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My freelance team and my work team both use [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) - Has SVN support and I think you can support Git with a module/plugin.